# Change not mapped color of a geom in a given plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a function which is not under my control, which returns a `ggplot` object, where the color of a `geom` is *not* mapped but assigned directly:

```
library(ggplot2)
notMyOwnFunction <- function(...) {
    qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, color = I("darkblue"))
}
```

How can I change the color **without** rewriting the whole function and replacing the constant `I("darkblue")` by a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change the literal value:

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, color = I("darkblue"))

# value starts as 'darkblue'    
gg$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour <- 'red'
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for w/o needing to decompose the whole object. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the data directly, using the `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable` functions for translation.

```
p <- notMyOwnFunction()
build <- ggplot_build(p)
build$data[[1]]$colour <- 'purple'
p_new <- ggplot_gtable(build)
plot(p_new)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution - arvi's solution is slightly shorter, but I learned again something - thx.